# How to create a table on word and add borders using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I simply want to create a table whenever I click on a command button. The table should have 2 rows and 2 columns.

And whenever I add another table, it should add a new one under the one before.

This is my code for now :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Content
MyRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=MyRange, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=2

End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that I dont see any borders and lines when I add it.

Also, When I click the command button several times, it just add more rows to the existing table, instead of creating other tables underneath the ones before.

I tried to add a line break between tables to fix the situation but it didnt work. I used :

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Text = "Foo" & Chr(11) & "Bar"
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you want borders? Or do you want gridlines (that don't print)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument.Range
  .InsertAfter vbCr
  .Tables.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=2
  .Tables(.Tables.Count).Borders.Enable = True
End With
End Sub
```